# Align the bottom nodes of mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, positioning, mindmaps

As you can see in the following figure, the bottom of the three nodes "Jupiter", "PA2AM", and "VPC" are not aligned. How to align them well?

[image: mindmap-bottom-align]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    root concept/.append style = {concept color = teal!30, sibling angle = 90, font = \LARGE, minimum size = 0pt},
    level 1 concept/.append style = {concept color = teal!30, sibling angle = 90, font = \large},
    level 2 concept/.append style = {concept color = teal!30, sibling angle = 60, font = \large},
  ] 
  \path[mindmap]
    node (spec) [concept, red] {\textsl{Specification}}
    [counterclockwise from = 225]

    child[purple] {
      node[concept] {\textsl{Imple-\\mentation}}
      [counterclockwise from = 240]
      child { node (cjupiter) [concept, font = \large] {Jupiter} }
      child { node (pa2am) [concept, font = \large] {PA2AM} }
    }
    child[violet] {
      node (veri) [concept] {\textsl{Veri-\\fication}}
      [clockwise from = -90]
      child { node (vpc) [concept, font = \large] {VPC} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course they are not aligned: The left two nodes are arranged around a circle, while the right one stems downward. All three children nodes share the same radius from their parent nodes. So it is clear that the solution is to specify the `level distance` for these three children nodes.

Here, I used `level distance=3cm` for the left two children nodes and `level distance=2.598cm` for the right one. This is basic trigonometry:

```
3cm * cos( -90 - 240 ) = 3cm * 0.866 = 2.598cm
```

**Suggestion** (not related to your question): Please don’t use manual line breaks `-\\`. Use `\-` instead to tell TeX where the hyphenation points are.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    root concept/.append style = {concept color = teal!30, sibling angle = 90, font = \LARGE, minimum size = 0pt},
    level 1 concept/.append style = {concept color = teal!30, sibling angle = 90, font = \large},
    level 2 concept/.append style = {concept color = teal!30, sibling angle = 60, font = \large},
  ] 
  \path[mindmap]
    node (spec) [concept] {\textsl{\color{red}Specification}}
    [counterclockwise from = 225]

    child[purple] {
      node[concept] {\textsl{Imple\-mentation}}
      [counterclockwise from = 240]
      child[level distance=3cm] { node (cjupiter) [concept, font = \large] {Jupiter} }
      child[level distance=3cm] { node (pa2am) [concept, font = \large] {PA2AM} }
    }
    child[violet] {
      node (veri) [concept] {\textsl{Veri\-fication}}
      [clockwise from = -90]
      child[level distance=2.598cm] { node (vpc) [concept, font = \large] {VPC} }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: nodes aligned]